# Looking for proof verification on a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A$ be an $n\times k$ matrix, and let $B$ be a $k\times m$ matrix. $AB$ is their product $n\times m$ matrix.

Prove:

> Part $1$: If $AB$ is one-to-one as a linear transformation, then so is $B$.
>
> Part $2$: If $AB$ is onto as a linear transformation, then so is $A$.

Proof: 
Part $1$:
If $AB$ is one to one, then $\mathrm{ker}(AB) = 0$. Let's prove that $\mathrm{ker}(B)$ is a subset of $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$. 
Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathrm{ker}(B)$. By definition of the kernel, $Bx = 0$. 
Then $ABx = A(Bx) = A0 = 0$.
So, $x$ is indeed included in $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$ and therefore $\mathrm{ker}(B)$ is a subset of $\mathrm{ker}(AB)$. This implies that $\mathrm{ker}(B) = \mathrm{ker}(AB) = 0$. Because $B$ has only one vector ($0$) that maps to zero, it is one to one.

Part $2$:
Since $AB$ is given to be onto, for every vector $y$ in the codomain of $AB$, there is a vector $x$ in the domain of $AB$ that maps to it, i.e.
$$
ABx = y.
$$
Let $z=Bx$, then
$$
Az = y.
$$
Since $y$ is also in the codomain of $A$, there exists a vector $z$ that maps to the entire codomain of $y$, so$ $A is onto.

Comments: I think I am making justifications that I will need to prove, such as "$y$ is in the codomain of $A$".

Comment: Both look correct; they could use a little bit of tidying up, but I don't see any problems with your reasoning, and no statements are made without justification.

Comment: You might structure the second one like this, it will go a little smoother: "Choose any $y$ in codomain of $A$. We must show $\exists z$ so that $Az = y$. Because $AB$ is onto, there exists $x$ so that $ABx = y$. Then, if we let $z = Bx$, we have $Az = y$, showing $A$ is onto." Same argument as yours, but I stated what we want to prove first, rather than in the middle of the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I still feel as if I am skipping some steps in part 2. How can we prove that AB and A have the same codomain? We are using vector y as any vector in the codomain for both regions.

Comment: It is clear that $A$ and $AB$ have the same codomain (write down explicitly what spaces $\Bbb R^k, \Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m$ they map between, if you like). If you had to prove they had the same *image* (for example), that would be more involved and require proof.